# Permit only WEB server in ACL on router?

Tags: vlan, acl, route-server

In that topology I need to configure

- 192.168.1.0/24 will block 10.10.20.20 host
- 192.168.2.0/24 will block 10.10.10.0/24 network
- All users can view web page but can't ping etc ...

I done that top 2 problems with extended named ACL, but I really can't third problem.

*you can look my topology and read my config*
[image]

*download full .pkt file ->https://megaup.net/8jat/lab6.pkt*

```
HQ(config)#ip access-list extended web
HQ(config-ext-nacl)#permit tcp host 180.220.0.10 any eq domain
HQ(config-ext-nacl)#permit tcp host 180.220.0.10 any eq www
HQ(config-ext-nacl)#deny ip any any
```

and HQ int se0/0/0 is **in** and other interfaces are **out**.

Where did i lose ? Also can't so understand about **in** and **out** it'll helpful if you explain more detail.

Comment: Looks like homework...

Comment: Unfortunately, all "_education, certification, or homework_" questions are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: Oh i don't know that. Where can i ask ?

Answer (score 2):

"In" and "Out" are directions from the point of view of the router.  So IN filters data coming from other devices into the router.  OUT filters data exiting the router on one of its interfaces.